# One Table Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update Price where PriceGroup = 'PG1' and Price is null, with the Price from the same ID but the PriceGroup is PG2.  I have tried a few solution here but couldn't find any with Where statement.

PriceTable:

```
Fields: ID, Price, PriceGroup
ABC,null,PG1
ABC,1.00,PG2
```

Result will be:

```
ABC,1.00,PG1
ABC,1.00,PG2
```

Comment: What SQL engine do you use?

Comment: MS SQL.  Great Answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Update priceTable
set price = (select b.price from PriceTable b where priceTable.id = b.id and price is not null )
where price is null
```

Tried with this data

```
INSERT INTO PriceTable VALUES(1, 1, 'PG1');
INSERT INTO PriceTable VALUES(1, null, 'PG2');
INSERT INTO PriceTable VALUES(2, 2,'PG3');
INSERT INTO PriceTable VALUES(2, null,'PG4');
```

and this is the output

```
before update
1|1|PG1
1||PG2
2|2|PG3
2||PG4
after update
1|1|PG1
1|1|PG2
2|2|PG3
2|2|PG4
```